# <iframe> in WebExtension popup doesn't load up at the start

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I made an  in a WebExtension popup but it doesn't load up at the start. It only loads when we click on the addon's button in the menu bar.

What can I do to make it load up at the start of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. It can't be done. Depending on what you need, you might want to consider a sidebar action:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sidebarAction

Instead of a popup.html file, you will have a sidebar.html file which is mentioned in manifest.json:

```
"sidebar_action": {
  "default_title": "My sidebar",
  "default_panel": "sidebar.html",
  "default_icon": "sidebar_icon.png"
}
```

Comment: Thanks fam! Can this .html file be from an external URL?

Comment: Also just to confirm that you didn't misunderstand my question, by "load up" I don't mean "show up" but rather that when the browser starts the external html file is loaded up

Comment: @JohnDoe The way you phrased the question doesn't really make that clear. You should probably make a new question (since this one already has a valid answer as-you-stated-it) detailing your requirements (external HTML, loaded on start, explanation _why_ - since it's likely you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: It will load the contents of the sidebar once you open it. I'm not sure when the content is unloaded (it is never unloaded while visible), but it should be less annoying than a browserAction which loads the content again every time you click on it.